# What is meant by "model discriminability for local patches within the receptive field"?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, papers, models

In the abstract of the paper [Network In Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4400.pdf), the authors write

> We propose a novel deep network structure called "Network In Network"(NIN) to enhance **model discriminability for local patches within the receptive field**

What does the part in bold mean?

Comment: This is also mentioned in Flattened Convolutional Neural Networks for Feedforward Acceleration: "We also use 1 × 1 filters across channels to increase model discriminability for local patches within the receptive field."